# Virt-Manager unsupported configuration: CPU mode 'custom

Tags: arch-linux, qemu

Getting the following error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'unsupported configuration: CPU mode 'custom'
for x86_64 kvm domain on x86_64 host is not supported by hypervisor'
```

Im using arch linux x64, Intel Core i7-6700K @ 8x 4.2GHz, x86_64 Linux 4.12.8-1-ARCH

Im selecting skylake-client under CPU options during installation but that is what I get. Can some one help? Maybe I'm missing something simple that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

After a LOT of reading into this, the solution is as easy as REBOOT YOUR HOST. :)

You will find everything works just fine, after you do.

Sometimes, even Windows hax work, on Linux

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since you already mentioned lots of reading, would you mind adding a few links to tutorials or other reference material where more information on your proposed solution can be found?

Answer (score 1):

Did not want to leave this hanging. I was able to solve the problem by selecting **[x] copy host cpu configuration** from the settings virt-manager. Im not sure why this works vs manually specifying the cpu architecture.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is likely that of insufficient permissions. Make sure that your user account is a member of *every* group required by your setup. I can't speak about arch, but to run `kvm` guests using `libvirt` on Ubuntu, you need to be a member of both `libvirt` and `kvm`.

Not being a member of the `kvm` gave me an empty cpu list which in turn resulted in the same:

```
ERROR    unsupported configuration: CPU mode 'custom' for ...
```

Answer (score 0):

x86_64 guest not supported by your hypervisor.
Seems like you have not enabled Virtualization Technology (vtx/vtd) in your bios.
Run this command to check it on your linux box

> grep -E '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: its enabled: `$ grep -E '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle`

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you get access restriction error, do not use the first "connexion" (qemu:///system) but create a new one called qemu:///session

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this problem that I ran into was that VirtualBox VM-s have been running. I stopped all VirtualBox VM-s and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

just set cpu-model be "host-passthrough"
like this:

```
<cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none"/>
```